# uncheck selected checkbox from check all in ext.js

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I have grid panel, its having check all options. But I'm stuck on the selected dataIndex which having value = 'N'. There is Y or N. If some rows having value N, it must not check when I click check all. I had already make validation on it. it's work. But I want also the uncheck is appear when i click check all if it's value is 'N'. This is my code

```
var sm;
sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel');
    gridMain = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: 'gridMyapproval',
        renderTo: Ext.get("sa-grid"),
        store: 'myapproval-store',
        selModel: sm,
        height: mainContentHeight - 63, //480//mainContentHeight-138,
        //title: 'Request',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Request Type',
            width: 100,
            dataIndex: 'WorkflowType'
        }, {
            text: 'Requestor ID',
            width: 100,
            dataIndex: 'RequestedByID'
        }, {
            text: 'Requestor Name',
            width: 200,
            dataIndex: 'RequestedByName'
        }, {
            text: 'Description',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'RequestDescription'
        }, {
            text: 'Status',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'RequestStatusDescription'
        },
        {
            text: 'EnableApprove',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'EnableApprove'
        },
        ],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [actApproveAll]
        }],
        listeners: {
            itemdblclick: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                isGridClicked = true;
                ViewDetails(FormState.VIEW);
            },
            afterrender: function (row, model, index) {
                //$('.x-column-header-checkbox').css('display','none');
               if (model.data.EnableApprove == 'N') {
                    grid.getSelectionModel().deselect();
                }
            },
            selectionchange: function (row, model, index) {
                if (model.data.EnableApprove == 'N') {
                    grid.getSelectionModel().deselect();
                }
            },
            beforeselect: function (row, model, index) {
                if (model.data.EnableApprove == 'N') {
                    MsgBox("Enable Approve !");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to write it on afterrenderer, but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to overrite [`selectAll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-method-selectAll) ([source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model2.html#Ext-selection-Model-method-selectAll)) and [`deselectAll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-method-deselectAll) ([source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model2.html#Ext-selection-Model-method-deselectAll)) methods of `Ext.selection.CheckboxModelView`.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142583/remove-ability-to-select-specific-rows-in-grid-extjs-4) and answer, I guess solution is somewhat you need.